# Setting up an array of collections in MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am creating a game where, as part of a collection named Game, I am trying to label one of the elements of it. The element in question is supposed to be an array of userNames from another collection. I can't seem to figure out how to access that. Here is what I have in the games collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = schema.ObjectId;

module.exports.Game = mongoose.model('Game', new schema({
    id:             ObjectId,
    gameRoomName:   { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.' },
    players:        {    }
}));
```

The users collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports.users = mongoose.model('Users', new schema({
    userName:       {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required.'}
}));
```

Basically, the usernames for a game will be saved in the Users schema. Then, I'd like to access that and insert it into the Game schema in the players space. I'm imagining it to be something like {type: collection.users}, however, that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: Your question was featured in a [commercial advertisement](https://youtu.be/4atMXqlaWPM?t=35).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store `players` as the array of references to `Users` model

```
module.exports.Game = mongoose.model('Game', new schema({
        .
        .
    players: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}],
)}
```

Access later by:

```
Game.find()
    // filter 'players' field
    .select('players')
    // populate players with only 'username' field
    .populate('players', 'username')
    .exec(function(err, username) {
        // anything with players
    });
```

Long story. You will be good to go after finishing the [article](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/)

Comment: if I have another element in the user schema (i.e. score), how to I access just the name, not the score too? If I'm understanding you (and the article, thx), the ref: 'Users' refers to the collection, while I'm trying to get down to a single element in the schema.

Comment: Yes, `ref: User` allow us to refer to `Users` model. Then we can call `populate()` to select the which field in `Users` we want to filter. (populate())[http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html]

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to solve the situation here...but ultimately I think it depends on what data you have readily available at the time you want to add the users into the game object and also how you want to retrieve the data when you need it.

If you have all the usernames cached, whether as objects or just the username itself, it would be more efficient to just add them into the game object.

Example:

```
var usernamesExample = ["Mike", "Ike", "Clara", "Joe"];

Game.findById(gameIdExample, function(error, foundGame){
  // handle errors/checks/etc.

  foundGame.players = usernamesExample;
  foundGame.save();
})
```

I personally think this approach is best performance wise. Then again it might not work for your situation, in which case I would need further clarification into how you obtain the username data for the game.